# How do Java REST calls relate to the front end of a Web Application?

Tags: javascript, java, rest, http

I am aware of how `REST` calls work from within a `Java` Web application. E.g. when a `URL` is reached its method will be called using `HTTP`.

For example:

```
 @GET
    @Path("people/{id}")
    public Response getPersonWithId(@PathParam("id") id) {

      //return the person object with that Id

    }
```

What I am *unsure* of is how this links to the front end?

Is the role of the UI ( i.e. `javascript` ) just to take a user to the specific URLs so that the back end methods can be called?

E.g. if a user presses a "get details" button, does the button just redirect them to this URL that deails with returning the details, and the back end functionality is then called?

Comment: When you press the getDetails button , you issue a HTTP GET to the URL you configured. And the method you wrote just returns an appropriate content type that will then be used for information display

Comment: It depends on the structure of your application. I like to separate my client and backend. This way, the API only sends data and the client knows how to present it. In your case getDetails would call a URL (optional with some data). Then the API returns the details (data) and the client presents this upon receiving.

Comment: @Bram can you please give an example of this?

Comment: An example of what? Look at any simple Ajax tutorial: client-side JS makes a request and does something with the return value, e.g., inserts it into the DOM if HTML was returned, transforms JSON into DOM elements or inserts a value into an existing element, and so on.

Comment: @DaveNewton any particular AJAX tutorial you recommend?

Comment: @java123999 Nope. Just search the web and pick one-there are hundreds, any of which will answer your basic questions. As you learn more you'll be able to target specific tutorials more easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebService is not actually linked or tied to the front end similar to webapp. Instead, webservice is a service that provides result in the form of JSON/XML, Plain text Format according to request type(get, post, update, delete) and hence, the service can be used by any multiple front end application(not only web application but also smartphone app, desktop app etc.). Also, webservice can be on totally different server.

Let me give you a scenario:

> > Suppose, you have an front end web site ABC-Website and a backend
> >     webservice on host: www.xyzservice.com/api with following methods:
> >
> > /product - get request that return all product as list in json format.
> >
> > /product/id  - get request return product detail given id in json
> >     format.
>
> Now, if you simply type in browser `www.xyzservice.com/api/product` then
>   all product list will displayed in json format in the browser. That means, You can also read data from webservice directly in browser without front end system and i.e. webservice is not linked/tied to any front end.

Now, you want to use this webservice in your ABC-Website to display all the product list:

```
You call www.xyzservice.com/api/products and get JSON object that you can use to display in your html page.

<button type="button" onclick="getProducts()">Click Me!</button> 

function getProducts(){ 
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "http://www.xyzservice.com/api/product",
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        success : function(data) {
            // now you have "data" which is in json format-same data that is displayed on browser.
            displayDate(date);      
        },
        error : function(e) {
            //do something
        },
        done : function(e) {
            //do something
        }
    });
}

function displayDate(){
    //your codes to parse and display json data  in html table in your page.
}
```

Comment: Thanks this has made it clearer. Does it matter in REST if the resource I am returning is from a database or from an xml file etc?

Comment: It would be prudent to mention that cross-site Ajax requests require CORS/etc.

Comment: It does not matter. Because whatever the source for your data (database, xml file, text file in harddisk etc.) is, you will parse and validate the data and return it from the API either in JSON, XML or simple text format and the client application that consumes the API will only get the data in either JSON/XML or text as configured in the API.

Answer (score 4):

Lets say that your client is a website and you have a Java API.

In the javascript of your website you could do a request to the backend to retrieve the data and then present it to the user. Your javascript (using jQuery as an example) could look like the following:

```
    // here it prints the data retrieved from the backend route (/people/{id}     
    $.get('http://localhost:3000/people/3',function onDataReceived(data) {
         console.log(data);
    })
```

As pointed out, jQuery is not necessary. Here is an example using regular javascript:

```
this.getRequest('http://localhost:3000/people/3', function onReceived(data) {

});

function getRequest(url, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true); 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so javascript is not really needed, HTML alone can be used?

Comment: JavaScript brings the dynamic functionality to HTML. HTML is just static presenting. You can alter the html using javascript. You have to call javascript from HTML (for example when a button is clicked).

Comment: @java123999 A language the browser understands is required. HTML alone is just that: HTML. You might want to take a step back and find some very basic tutorials about how dynamic websites work.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and your input also @DaveNewton. Does it matter in REST if the resource I am returning is from a database or from an xml file etc?

Comment: @java123999 REST is a resource naming convention and nothing more. What the resource *is* is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok so the resource could be a database / xml / json etc?

Comment: REST defines the following operations on data: create, delete, update and GET. These operations are usually implemented in an API (a service layer which serves data). The API then accesses the data source to retrieve the data. In our case your Java API is the service layer which should access the database / xml / whatever data source. The client (in your case a website) just calls the API and says: /people/2. The client does not care about where the data comes from it just wants the user data. The service layer then accesses the data source to gather the data and serve it back to the caller.

Comment: This separates the concerns of all parties. Lets say you want to also build a mobile app. You can just call the same route (/people/2) and do not have to re-implement the whole data retrieving and mapping part. This way, the client can focus on what it does best: presenting data.

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, usually you want to do these request at the background your webpage.

Im gonna try to explain this with an example:

Imagine you have a page that displays a list of cars for sell which can be fetched from the web service provided by java back-end. The back-end have an url that will respond to GET method with a JSON (or XML) object.

What you have is a HTML file where you write a structure for the displayed data and also includes a javascript file that asynchronously calls this webservice, GETs the data, parses the JSON and then it can manipulate it to the form you want to display it on the page.

In different example you can validate forms on the background, or save the forms or do any other stuff that works with the web service API.

For making these asynchronous request you can use different libraries.

Most used is ajax included in [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) framework or [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) as n standalone library.